# way to fix date and time in my laptop which has been installed with ubuntu dualboot

Tags: windows, date, time

I am using Ubuntu as a dual boot in my windows laptop. Every time I go from Ubuntu to windows the time displayed on my laptop is wrong. I always need to go to settings and sync the time. Can the time displayed in my windows be in sync?